# Solution of this specific (equation with trigonometric terms) system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Given a system of linear equations with $N$ unknowns an $M$ equations $(N<M)$ its not too difficult to see if there is a solution.

Now consider an extended system of equations where a term in an equation can be either a simple variable or $\sin()$ or $\cos()$ of a variable (or its multiple). The power of each term is still 1. For eg:

$15\sin(10x)-5y+3\cos(7z)=0$

Given any problem instance, can this system be solved systematically/easily? The number of unknowns is still greater than the number of equations.

**Edit:** My background is CS and not mathematics and this is a problem that arose out of a self-study scenario (from pure Linear algebra). So not much to go about in external help. I am unaware what this set of equations are actually called so couldn't look for help online either.

Comment: The reason that your posting is garnering down-votes, and votes-to-close is that there is information missing from your posting.  What is your Math background?  What is the source of the problem?  What tools (i.e. theorems, worked examples, previously solved problems) do think might be pertinent?  Please also show a significant effort to use the tools to attack the problem.  It does not matter if you succeed, only that you tried.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Hint : with your example, set $X=\sin(10x),Y=\cos(7z)$ giving rise to linear equation $15X-5y+3Z=0$ and so on for the other equations. Solve this system and check only in a second step the various compatibilites for example $|X| \le 1$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you. But that is one example equation.  For example in a three system the equations can be: (1) $15\sin(10x)-5y+3\cos(7z)=0$ (2) $23\sin(7x)-17y+5\cos(19z)=0$ (3) $24\sin(6x)-17\cos(37y)-35\cos(16z)=0$. This would still be 3 unknowns $x, y, z$ but if I assume the variable assignment as you suggested the number of variables might quickly exceed the number of  equations. So i think that won't work?

Comment: @user2661923 I truly understand what you mean but in self study sometimes there is no 'source' for the problem and neither (as in this case) one knows how to begin. Its a Q that arose out of linear algebra. A generalized system rather than a simple linear algebra eq. I don't know how to begin or go about here..

Comment: What do you mean? The solution set is a surface given as the graph $$y= 3\sin(10x)+\frac35\cos(7z).$$ There's nothing else to say.

Comment: That is an example of a single equation! The Q is given ANY generic set of equations which are linear but instead of variables also can have a sin or cos of the variable can they be efficiently solved? the variables in the example are $x, y, z$ and not $10x, 7z$ etc. Additionally, $N < M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little matured my thoughts : IMHO, nothing can be said in general, no general methodology can be applied.

Let us consider for example the system you have given:

$$\begin{cases}15\sin(10x)-5y+3\cos(7z)&=&0\\
23\sin(7x)-17y+5\cos(19z)&=&0\\
24\sin(6x)-17\cos(37y)-35\cos(16z)&=&0\end{cases}$$

Let us use a classical "trick" : fix a value of $z$ (which is parameter $a$ for Desmos), for understanding the kind of complexity we have to deal with :

[image]

You can see how strange some of the curves (the black one here) may behave, for a given value of $a$ (here $a=1.5$). When $a$ moves, one can spot values where, apparently, the three curves have (at least) a common point, but how complicated it is with only 3 variables !

The complexity is enhanced by the fact that a variable such as $y$ can appear "naked" (equations (1) and (2)) or "coated" with a trigonometric function, here $\cos(37y)$ in equation (3). I think you have to avoid this mixed use.

Comment: thank you. as you suggested mixed use might case issues. I understand. Now we further restrict ourselves so that all variables that appear only in sin or cos. This by definition won't be mixed. would that simplify the problem?

Comment: I think so... Another track : consider the issue with a geometrical eye. For example with the 3rd equation written under the form of a dot product $(24,-17,-35) . (\sin(6x),\cos(37y),\cos(16z))=0$, Then divide by the norm of the first vector by its norm $\sqrt{24^2+17^2+35^2}$, meaning that we have an **orthogonality constraint** between a vector of the unit (hyper ?)sphere and a vector which is included in the unit (hyper) cube.